# How can I keep IDEA from changing my active tab when I open other files

Tags: intellij-idea

A little annoying thing, but it happens all the time...

Here I am, minding my own business, coding away happily. I have CatClass.java and DogClass.java open in different groups (and usually lots of other files as well):

[image: step 1]

I want to open and edit CatService.java:

[image]

Unfortunately it opened in the wrong group, I wanted to see it side by side with CatClass.java. So I decide to move CatService.java to the other side:

[image]

Boom! Now the original group is not anymore in the CatClass.java, but has changed to some other file.

This is seriously my biggest problem with IDEA, I usually have tens of files open in both groups and digging through the tabs, getting back the file I was in just a moment ago, really hurts the flow. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a known (old) bug:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125946

Comment: I don't think this works as you described. At least for me it did not change which tab was active after I moved CatService.java.  https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/pinning-and-unpinning-tabs.html says that pinning relates to when tab limit (10) is reached and some tabs are *closed*, and this did not happen in this case.

I noticed a setting Editor -> Editor tabs -> Tab Closing Policy -> When closing active editor: "Activate most recently opened tab" which fixes the problem when *closing* CatService.java. It does not help when *moving* CatService.java, though unfortunately.

Comment: This worked for me but I guess by accident. Did a little research I found that this is a bug - see updated answer above.

Comment: Sorry, forgot this for a while. Yes, the only way to solve this seems to be to wait until Jetbrains fixes that bug. Like the reporter says, "This is my #1 most annoying problem in IDEA, I hit it several times an hour."